# Dynamic cart icon image with number in ASP

Tags: asp.net, database, dynamic, png

I've seen this about a bazillion times but I'm a front-end guy and writing ASP (we have a .Net/Modified MS StoreFront setup) is not my forté. I want to create a cart icon/image with the number of how many items are in the basket displayed in the image dynamically. These would display in a little red bubble over the cart icon. If there are no items in the basket, the red bubble wouldnt even display. I'm just not sure at how to accomplish it. Thanks in advance for any advice!

For the basic text return, the DB call is:

```
((!NUM_CART_ITEMS!))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do text positioning over image as discussed in the following link:

[Placing text over image using CSS position property](http://frinity.blogspot.in/2008/06/placing-text-over-image-using-css.html)

Eg.

```
<div><img src="YOUR-IMAGE-URL" /></div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 160px;">
PUT-TEXT-NEED-TO-BE-DISPLAYED-ON-IMAGE
</div>
```

Modify the style attribute as per your needs. You can use **absolute or relative** positioning as per you needs.